# Clip image background/ rounded corner CSS only

Tags: html, image, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have one part in web site design I cannot realize how to implement better.

This is the part of the page. You can see where content will be according to guidelines (bootstrap grid).
And the most important part is rounded borders at the bottom and top.

[image]

I have tried to play with `border` property, but couldn't get desired result.

Is there any way to achieve following effect using only CSS, **without using modern browser features like clip,canvas ...**, to support mobile browsers.
Or there is only way to export background already in a proper shape from graphical editor ?

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: The easiest solution might be to create the image with a transparent background.

Comment: You mean image with already shape set ?

Comment: yes. that's probably the easiest method everyone would go for.

Comment: Definitely the easiest solution from @JinuKurian - but you could also consider using a flat bg image, then a second div on top, with top and bottom borders that are thick and slightly rounded.

Answer (score 2):

This is the closest i could get:

```css
div {
  position:absolute;
  left:40px;
  top:40px;
  width:500px;
  height:300px;
  border-radius:100%/20px;
  background: blue url(https://placeimg.com/500/300/any);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, could you please explain how `border-radius` is calculated using percentage and px ? (what is 100% ) in this case ? And how well is this method supported across browsers ?